# How can I set the app locale as prefix for all my laravel routes automatically?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get the actual app locale as prefix for all my routes in automated way, atm I'm giving it as parameter every time I call a route like that:

web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function() {

    Route::get(__('contact'), function () {
        return view('pages.contact');
    })->name('contact');

});
```

header.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('contact', app()->getLocale())}}">@lang('contact')</a>
</li>
```

This actually works, it display en_US/contact for example, is there a way to avoid giving the locale on the route call?

EDIT: after some answered I followed the documentation in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#default-values, so my code looks something like this:

middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetDefaultLocaleForUrls
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['locale' => app()->getLocale()]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

kernel.php:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
....
'locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultLocaleForUrls::class,
....
];
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'middleware' => 'locale'], function () {
    Route::get(__('contact'), function () {
            return view('pages.welcome');
        })->name('contact');
});
```

but still needing to give locale what i'm doing wrong?

```
"Missing required parameters for [Route: contact] [URI: {locale}/contact]"
```

EDIT2: Noticed middleware only works when I set the locale parameter on the URL, if I don't write it it doesnt trigger, maybe there is the error

Comment: You could use a middleware. check if the locale has changed and than set it....
smth like this: class SetLocale
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
    }
}

Answer (score 4):

You can set the default value for a url with the `URL::defaults()` method. You can put this in a middleware to make it work for all routes.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetDefaultLocaleForUrls
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->user()->locale]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It is mentioned in the docs here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#default-values

Comment: I created the middleare, registered it on kernel and using it like this: Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'middleware' => 'locale'], function () {
 Route::get(__('contact'), function () {
      return view('pages.welcome');
  })->name('contact');
}); but still i need the parameter on blade, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is inside your middleware now? if you set the value to null it will still give the same Exception

Comment: I edited it with the middleware code, also I still getting the same exception, can't manage to get /en_US/contact url working without setting it on blade