Error in the controllers of my localized routes because it expects $locale as first variable in every functions
I am adding localization in my Laravel app.
Let's say I have the routes slots and slots/{id}. My problem is, when I try to go to slots/{id} page, the controller that handles this route expects $locale as the first variable of the function.
This is my function:
public function show($locale, Slot $slot)
{
    dump($locale);
    return view('slots.show', [
        'slot' => $slot,
    ]);
}

What I'd like is avoid having to pass the $locale variable to every functions of my controllers. Is there a way to do that? Like this:
public function show(Slot $slot)
{
    return view('slots.show', [
        'slot' => $slot,
    ]);
}

I am trying to achieve this without having to add any package like laravel-localization.
This is my middleware:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));

        URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}

This is what my web.php looks like:
Route::prefix('{locale}')
    ->where(['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'])
    ->middleware('setlocale')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::domain('{portal:slug}.' . env('APP_DOMAIN'))->name('portal.')->group(function () {    
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        });

        Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'institution', 'goodDb'])->group(function () {
                    Route::resource('slots', SlotController::class);

    });

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I had the same issue before, I used named parameters in my app which turned out to be good, it's my preferred way now, like this $request->route('parameter_name') ($request is injected)

you can remove a certain param by adding $request->route()->forgetParameter('locale'); in your SetLocale Middleware's handle method (before return $next($request);).

does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463408/how-can-i-set-the-app-locale-as-prefix-for-all-my-laravel-routes-automatically

@zahidhasanemon 's answer seems to be working. I'm still doing a little bit of testing. Thanks a lot for your help guys!
